# How to access properties of object from Stub?

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

I have simple class:

```
class MyClass {

    private $myProperty;

    public __construct($propertyValue) {
        $this->myProperty= $propertyValue;
    }

    public function myMethod() {
        // Something
    }

}
```

And class what using MyClass:

```
class MySecondClass {

    private $myClass;

    public __construct($myClassInst) {
        $this->myClass = $myClassInst;
    }

    public function doIt() {
        $this->myClass->myMethod();
    }

}
```

And I have unit test for some MySecondClass class:

```
use Codeception\TestCase\Test;
use Codeception\Util\Stub;

class MySecondClassTest extends Test

    public function testDoIt() {
        $data = null;

        $myClass = Stub::construct('MyClass', ['propertyValue'], [
            'myMethod' => function() use (&$data) {
                // I want do that, but I can not!
                //$data = $this->myProperty;
            }

        $mySecondClass = new MySecondClass($myClass);
        $mySecondClass->doIt();

        $this->assertEquals($data, 'assertValue');
    ]);

}
```

If to uncomment lines in example above:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined variable: myProperty ...
```

In case of myProperty is public:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined property: MySecondClassTest::$myProperty
```

Question: How to access property `myProperty` of `MyClass` from Stub if `$this` referencing to object of class MySecondClassTest there?

Comment: you could either set `myProperty` scope as public, or define a getter method (with `public` scope) in your `Myclass` class. Something like `public function getMyProperty() {return $this->myProperty;}`

Comment: Question is how to access myProperty from Stub? There are not working $this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yagni. You are testing logic in `MySecondClass::doIt` ,not in `MyClass`.

You mock `MyClass`, and define exact response from `MyClass::myMethod` with constant value. Basically, your `testDoIt()` reads: Given we have an instance of `MyClass` that return some exact value, we expect `MySecondClass::doIt` to return some exact value. That's it. Nothing to do with `MyClass::myProperty` at all.

**EDIT** 
in answer to the comment

> In case of public property it is error too, because $this references to MySecondClassTest object: PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined property: MySecondClassTest::$myProperty

First of all, I think you misunderstand concept of test doubles. Stub is not an instance of the mocked class. It is a stub. It **imitates** behaviour of the mocked class, and only in the defined part.

Secondly, `$this` in a closure always refers to the class where the closure is defined. In your case it is `MySecondClassTest`.

Again, the problem is not in visibility of the property, but in the fact that you need value of this property in your test. You do not. It violates the core principle of unittesting.

Comment: It is just example, question is how to access properties of object from stub?Is there such a possibility, in principle?

Comment: This example perfectly illustrates the mistake. If you need value of the private property of the mocked class in your test, your test is wrong.

Comment: In case of public property it is error too, because $this references to MySecondClassTest object: PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Undefined property: MySecondClassTest::$myProperty